# how do I copy a file to all user accounts

Tags: user-accounts

OSX Yosemite server - 150 odd networked user accounts - is there a way to copy a file (such as a Safari Extension) to the same relative location in each user account?

Answer (score 0):

A simple terminal action will do this in seconds

cp -rvn /original/file/location/file.name /folderofuseraccounts/*/subfolderlocation/subfolder/

do a "man cp" (in terminal) if you're not familiar.
 the various switches are quite helpful.
-r (recursive - it'll copy all subfolders)
-v (verbose - it'll tell you what it's doing on-screen)
-n (don't overwrite - won't overwrite a file in target destination if it finds one)

Combine this with a launchd, and you can do regular updates to all your user accounts in a really simple way.

another way to do this is to do an 'rsync' of a particular folder on your server INTO a particular folder on all users...